# Masstransit: How to build a cache filter in the Mediator

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

We used the Masstransit Mediator to write request/response "Consumers" called from API controllers. Before the consumer is taken action, some ConsumeFilters take place: Logging, Validation and DBTransaction. Next I would like to implement a Cache Filter using simple Microsoft In-Memory Cache. The filter should check if the request object is already in cache, if not the consumer pipe is called and the cache object is added, else the cached object should be returned immediatly.

I could not figure out how write such a filter. Do I need two filters? If I call RespondAsync from ConsumeContext how can a use a generic response type?

Has someone done it before, or should I do I directly in consumer?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like something that should be in the consumer itself. The cache itself could be a dependency of the consumer, which is a single instance and injected into the consumer via the constructor. That way, it would be able to check if the results are in the cache before calling the backing service with the request detail.

Hiding that in a filter seems a little specific to the message type, so within the consumer will likely be easier for developers to understand later.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to integrate in-memory caching as mass transit scope filter. Currently it is only used in a mediator. Some prequists:

- All messages are records (with value bases equal methods)
- The query request object inherits from ApplicationQueryRequest (a record)
- The query response objects inherits from ApplicationResponse (a record)

The request object has an attribute named Cached Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class CacheAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CacheAttribute(int slidingExpireSecs = 30, int absoluteExpireSecs = 100)
    {
       SlidingExpireSecs = slidingExpireSecs;
       AbsoluteExpireSecs = absoluteExpireSecs;
   }

    public int SlidingExpireSecs { get; }

    public int AbsoluteExpireSecs { get; }
```

}

Therefore each request object can have a cache attribute like:

```
[Cache]
public record FooRequest
{

}
```

Target is that the filter automatically fetches data from the cache and stores data in it.

First initialize the mediator with all consumer and send fiters, in our case only one scope filter exists but must be added for send and consume:

```
        services.AddMediator(
        configurator =>
        {
            (context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.UseSendFilter(typeof(CacheScopeFilter<>), context);                           
                cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(CacheScopeFilter<>), context);
```

Additionally the ICacheScope must be of

services.AddScoped...

THe scope filter looks like this:

```
public class CacheScopeFilter<T> :
    IFilter<SendContext<T>>,
    IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>> where T : class
{
    private readonly ILogger<T> logger;
    private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;
    private readonly ICacheScope cacheScope;
    private CacheOptions cacheOptions;

    public CacheScopeFilter(ILogger<T> logger, IOptionsMonitor<CacheOptions> options, IMemoryCache memoryCache, ICacheScope cacheScope)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        cacheOptions = options.CurrentValue;
        options.OnChange(
                opts =>
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"Set Memory Cache enabled: {opts.EnableMemoryCache}");
                    cacheOptions = opts;
                });
        this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
        this.cacheScope = cacheScope;
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        var requestName = typeof(T).Name;

        logger.LogInformation($"----- Start check cache application query request {requestName} {context.Message}");

        cacheScope.RequestKey = null;

        if (context.TryGetMessage<ApplicationQueryRequest>(out var requestContext))
        {
            if(!cacheOptions.EnableMemoryCache)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Cache is disabled");
                await next.Send(context);
                return;
            }

            var cacheAttribute = (CacheAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                requestContext.Message.GetType(),
                typeof(CacheAttribute));

            if (cacheAttribute == null)
            {
                await next.Send(context);
                return;
            }

            cacheScope.RequestKey = typeof(T).FullName + ";" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Message);
            cacheScope.SlidingExpireSecs = cacheAttribute.SlidingExpireSecs;
            cacheScope.AbsoluteExpireSecs = cacheAttribute.AbsoluteExpireSecs;

            if (memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheScope.RequestKey, out ApplicationResponse cacheResponse))
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Take data from cache {requestName} {context.Message}, CacheKey: {cacheScope.RequestKey}");

                await context.RespondAsync(cacheResponse);
                return;
            }

            logger.LogInformation($"Data not in cache, fetching data {requestName} {context.Message}");
        }

        await next.Send(context);

        logger.LogInformation($"----- Finish check cache application query request {requestName} {context.Message}");
    }

    public async Task Send(SendContext<T> context, IPipe<SendContext<T>> next)
    {
        var requestName = typeof(T).Name;

        logger.LogInformation($"----- Start handling cache application query response {requestName} {context.Message}");

        var isCachedSet = context.TryGetPayload<CacheDoneMarker>(out _);

        if (context.Message is ApplicationResponse && (cacheScope.RequestKey != null) && !isCachedSet)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Cache data {requestName} {context.Message}, CacheKey: {cacheScope.RequestKey}");

            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().
                                    SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(cacheScope.SlidingExpireSecs)).
                                    SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(cacheScope.AbsoluteExpireSecs));

            memoryCache.Set(cacheScope.RequestKey, context.Message, cacheEntryOptions);

            context.GetOrAddPayload(() => new CacheDoneMarker());
        }

        await next.Send(context);

        logger.LogInformation($"----- Finish handling cache application query response {requestName} {context.Message}");
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateFilterScope("cache");
    }
}
public class CacheScope : ICacheScope
{
    public string RequestKey { get; set; }

    public int SlidingExpireSecs { get; set; }

    public int AbsoluteExpireSecs { get; set; }
}

// Scope injected !
public interface ICacheScope
{
    public string RequestKey { get; set; }

    public int SlidingExpireSecs { get; set; }

    public int AbsoluteExpireSecs { get; set; }
}
```

This should also work for distributed cache, but not added yet.